# React Native: how to load binary file from remote?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to fetch audio-files from remote storage. How can i use the response-result from method "fetch" to handle binary data? i want to save them in local filesystem with react-native-fs. But i can't find nowhere a documentation of the return-value of method "fetch" to access the binary blob.
I tried to console.log the response of fetch, but with binary data, xcode is hanging then being unresponsible

I am looking for something like this:

```
    fetch(mediaUrl).then( (response) => {
        let blob = response.getBinaryData()
    })
```

(getBinaryData is'nt a valid method. And exactly this is my question: how to obtain the binary data?)

## Update

some people points to "response.blob()", but this method is not implemented in react-native.

> "response.blob is not a function. (In 'response.blob()',
> 'response.blob' is undefined)"

Answer (score 2):

I've totally forgotten this (outdated) question of myself nearly one and a half year ago and will finally provide a suitable answer:

With the library [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) one can download binary files and stores them binary on disk storage, that audio-files can played well with [react-native-sound](http://react-native-sound) and video-files for instance can be played well with [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video).

## Example code:

```js
  const downloadOptions = {
    fromUrl: imageUrl,
    toFile: filename
  }
  return yield RNFS.downloadFile(downloadOptions).promise.then( (res) => {
    if(res.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      console.log("Download failed", res);
      return false;
    }

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('DownloadFile Error', err);
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: It's great until you have to get it from S3 or you get it from other place where downloadFile will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while investigating this.  I'm sure there's more to know but I'd start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob

Here's a working RN code snippet.

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
opts = {}
return fetch(url, opts)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    console.log('blob', blob);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
      console.log(reader.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

Comment: In react-native, blob() is not implemented as a function: "response.blob is not a function. (In 'response.blob()', 'response.blob' is undefined)"

Comment: @itinance thats saving the image either as `base64`, `ascii` or `utf-8` encoded. Any ideas how to save it directly as `.png` in the local filesystem?

Comment: @Stophface plz look at my own answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46443715/1397160